# JQuery UI Draggable and touch-punch in Android default browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, android-browser, jquery-ui-touch-punch, touch-punch

I'm trying to implement drag and drop behavior  using JQuery UI with Touch Punch library (http://touchpunch.furf.com/). Everything works fine in all browsers on android and ios, except default android browser. In simplest examples provided on touchpunch site everyting works, but when you have many droppable areas (or in some other cases) drag and drop in default android browser doesn't work (or works terribly). I wrote an example for this situation:
http://jsfiddle.net/u6cNS/166/

```
$(".drag" ).draggable();
$(".drop" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html( "Got it!" );
    }
});
```

(see html on jsfiddle)

Any solutions or workarounds are welcome.

Comment: i suggest you also provide android version

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'accept' option in case of multiple droppable area.

here it explains how to use it : http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept

Comment: It doesn't change anything. It still works very glitchy in Android Default browser. Here is the same example with 'accept' option:
http://jsfiddle.net/u6cNS/176/